# Radius of a circle when equation has coefficients

Tags: trigonometry, circles

This is the equation of a circle when coefficients a,b,c,d are > 0.

$\frac{(x-a)^2 + y^2}{b} = \frac{(x-c)^2 + y^2}{d}$

Is there a way to transform it to the center and radius form?.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, do the algebra: collect terms and simplify. It will not be pretty in general.

Comment: @rogerl It is "pretty" in fact (depends on what is called "pretty"...) by conversion into $\text{dist}((x,y),(a,0))=k \ \text{dist}((x,y),(b,0))$ with $k=\sqrt{b/d}$, giving a so-called Apollonius circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expand $$d\big[(x-a)^2 + y^2\big]- b\big[(x-c)^2 + y^2\big]=0$$ you have
$$(d-b)x^2+2(bc-ad)x+(d-b)y^2+(a^2d-bc^2)=0$$ Compare to
$$f\big[(x-A)^2+y^2\big]-g=0$$

This will give
$$f=d-b   \qquad \qquad A=\frac{b c-a d}{b-d}\qquad \qquad g=\frac{b d (a-c)^2}{d-b}$$